# Import a jpeg file and a mov file and display them side by side

Tags: import, output-formatting, animation

I am planning to use *Mathematica* for a presentation. In one of the slides I need to place a jpeg file side by side to a mov file.

```
Row[{ImageResize[Import["compressor.jpeg"], 1500], Import["kiwi.mov","Animation"]}]
```

There is a huge difference in size between the jpeg figure and the mov file. I could click on the jpeg file and change its size but the outcome is not nice (too big for showing in just one slide).

**Is there a set of options (commands or a complete different solution) that I can use to have both jpeg and mov dimensions set to a specific size?** I could not figure out how to change the size of the Animation frame. I can click and change the size of the movie itself but not the size of the frame.

Many thanks.

Comment: The documentation mentions that `Animate` takes the same options as `Manipulate`; among those there is a `ContentSize` option that you could use to change the size of the contents of your `Animate` pane.

Comment: @MarcoB.  Many thanks but I am not sure how to set ContentSize within Import.   Import takes only 2 parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could import each frame of your movie as a separate image, then use `ListAnimate` on this list to generate an animation on which you would then have full control.

I am going to generate a static image and a test movie to play with:

```
staticimage = Rasterize@Plot[Sin[x], {x, -Pi, Pi}, AspectRatio -> 1, ImageSize -> Medium];
Table[Rasterize@Plot[Sin[i x], {x, -Pi, Pi}, AspectRatio -> 1], {i, 1, 5, 0.5}];
Export["test.mov", %]
```

Now I use `Import` to obtain a **list of frames** from the test movie. You already know how to import the image you need, so I will just assume that the image has been stored in `staticimage` for the purposes of this toy example. I then set the **dimensions** of the `ListAnimate` output to those of the static image.

```
GraphicsRow[{
  staticimage,
  ListAnimate[
   Import["test.mov", "ImageList"],
   ImageSize -> ImageDimensions[staticimage]
  ]
}]
```

[image: animated plot]

`ListAnimate` gives you a lot of control over the resulting animation: you can set the framerate, the duration, whether it will continue indefinitely, etc. It is worth your time to take a look at its [documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListAnimate.html).

Comment: Unfortunately it did not work with the mov file I have. ListAnimate works separately but not with the static image.

Comment: @EdMendes what exactly went wrong?

Comment: I can see the image and a box with a black strip on it.  No animation though. The movie is there but it has not been resized so that is the reason I can only see a very tiny strip of it.

Comment: @EdMendes Do you know the absolute sizes of the image and movie? I'd like to see if I can reproduce the problem on this end with the toy example I have already in place.

Comment: Unfortunately not.  Would Import with imageSize do?  If so, sizes  are: {1280, 960} for the picture and {588, 632} for the movie.  Many thanks.